# Sunshine hours duration calclulated from r.sun (GRASS Plug in) are same for diffrent date

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

Currently i am trying to calculate sunshine hours duration from r.sun (GRASS Plug in ) from QGIS 2.12. I want to calculate sunshine duration for 21 st jun and 21st December for same elevation data set. After time consuming process i managed to get sunshine duration. But when i saw output for summer as well as winter both duration hours value are same. Is it related to DEM size or tools issue. because similar process i run with ArcGIS solar radiation tools and got very accurate results. if anybody worked on this please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen this blog post using r.sun.hourly from GRASS:
http://courses.neteler.org/will-the-sun-shine-on-us/

Comment: Yes thanks. nice post actually but its difficult ti get my answer from that post..

Comment: please add the key elements of that post to this answer, incase in the future it goes away.